# Prevent SQL Injection: Do I need to escape input before binding values into a PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

1. In the scenario below, $user_id is strings entered by a user. 
   I'm wondering if I still need to escape the strings first with `$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"])` and `$name= htmlentities($_POST["name"])`?

   ```
   $query = "INSERT INTO user ('email','name') VALUES (?,?)";
   $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($query);
   $this->_query->bindValue(1, $email);
   $this->_query->bindValue(2, $name);
   $this->_query->execute();
   ```
2. I saw some people don't escape the input before insert query but they do escape data before echo it out. Why do thay do this?

   ```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
   $this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($query);
   $this->_query->bindValue(1, $user_id);
   $this->_query->execute();
   $data = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $output = $data[0]["name"];
   $output = htmlentities($output);
   echo output;
   ```
3. Is it neccessary to use htmentities() before and after the query?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between SQL and HTML, by chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Quotes around tables/columns are incorrect. Use backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape/convert HTML to avoid a SQL injection if you're using prepared queries. As for when you need to use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`, you will need that if you output user-provided data to a web-page. Not doing that makes you vulnerable to [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) (Cross-Site Scripting) injections, ie. malicious javascript that gets executed in the browser on page load. Recommended reading: [XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet).

Aside SQL and XSS injection prevention, you may also want to do other checks on user input, such as validating e-mail addresses, username characters, etc. before you input them into your DB. Otherwise you're up for some tedious database cleaning down the road. You may want to look into [PHP's filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), basic regex that removes everything outside white-listed character ranges, etc.

Comment: Welcome. Added some more "sanity" leads for you to look into.

Answer (score 1):

1. No; a parameterized query is safe from SQL-injection attacks.
2. & 3.  This is using `htmlentities()`, which isn't exactly escaping the output.  The primary benefit of using this is it protects you from [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), which is very different from SQL-injection.  This sanitizes user input and prevents a user from running a malicious `<script>` on your webpage.